# image upload and crop client side including on old browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I am looking for some sort of image uploader and cropper that works mainly client side before it saves to the server.

I have tried a few things but have the issue that most of it is html5 based and I can't seem to find some sort of flash based uploader for the older browsers.

I got slightly lost with the jquery file uploader which I know can be used in the older browsers and the still need to work on a cropping function (but that looks like it will be mostly server side which would be a last resort).

I have also used http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/ which sort of works it uploads but when I want to test the crop function it keeps opening up the upload.php file. I will put the code below here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>test image uploader</title>

    <!--Stylesheets-->
    <link  href="css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css"  rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- scripts-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body >
  <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
        <input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
        <input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />

        <h2>Please select image file</h2>
        <div>
            <input  type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler();"/>
        </div>

        <div class="error"></div>

        <div class="step2">
            <h2>Please select a crop region</h2>
            <img id="preview" />

            <div class="info">
                <label>File size</label><input type="text" id="filesize" name="filesize" />
                <label>Type</label><input type="text" id="filetype" name="filetype" />
                <label>Image dimension</label><input  type="text" id="filedim" name="filedim" />
                <label>W</label><input type="text" id="w" name="w" />
                <label>H</label><input type="text" id="h" name="h" />
            </div>

            <input  type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // convert bytes into friendly format
        function bytesToSize(bytes) {
            var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
            if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
            var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
            return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        };

        // check for selected crop region
        function checkForm() {
            if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
            $('.error').html('Please select a crop region and then press Upload').show();
            return false;
        };

        // update info by cropping (onChange and onSelect events handler)
        function updateInfo(e) {
            $('#x1').val(e.x);
            $('#y1').val(e.y);
            $('#x2').val(e.x2);
            $('#y2').val(e.y2);
            $('#w').val(e.w);
            $('#h').val(e.h);
        };

        // clear info by cropping (onRelease event handler)
        function clearInfo() {
            $('.info #w').val('');
            $('.info #h').val('');
        };

        function fileSelectHandler() {

            // get selected file
            var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];

            // hide all errors
            $('.error').hide();

            // check for image type (jpg and png are allowed)
            var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;
            if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
                $('.error').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
                return;
            }

            // check for file size
            if (oFile.size > 250 * 1024) {
                $('.error').html('You have selected too big file, please select a one smaller image file').show();
                return;
            }

            // preview element
            var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

            // prepare HTML5 FileReader
            var oReader = new FileReader();
            oReader.onload = function (e) {

                // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we can use as a source of the image
                oImage.src = e.target.result;
                oImage.onload = function () { // onload event handler

                    // display step 2
                    $('.step2').fadeIn(500);

                    // display some basic image info
                    var sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
                    $('#filesize').val(sResultFileSize);
                    $('#filetype').val(oFile.type);
                    $('#filedim').val(oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight);

                    // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size
                    var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

                    // destroy Jcrop if it is existed
                    if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined')
                        jcrop_api.destroy();

                    // initialize Jcrop
                    $('#preview').Jcrop({
                        minSize: [100, 100], // min crop size
                        boxWidth:600,
                        aspectRatio: 9/6, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
                        bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                        bgOpacity: .4, // fade opacity
                        onChange: updateInfo,
                        onSelect: updateInfo,
                        onRelease: clearInfo
                    }, function () {

                        // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                        var bounds = this.getBounds();
                        boundx = bounds[0];
                        boundy = bounds[1];

                        // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                        jcrop_api = this;
                    });
                };
            };

            // read selected file as DataURL
            oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

here is the upload.php code :

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * HTML5 Image uploader with Jcrop
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2012, Script Tutorials
 * http://www.script-tutorials.com/
 */

function uploadImageFile() { // Note: GD library is required for this function

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $iWidth = $iHeight = 200; // desired image result dimensions
        $iJpgQuality = 90;

        if ($_FILES) {

            // if no errors and size less than 250kb
            if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 250 * 1024) {
                if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])) {

                    // new unique filename
                    $sTempFileName = 'cache/' . md5(time().rand());

                    // move uploaded file into cache folder
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $sTempFileName);

                    // change file permission to 644
                    @chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);

                    if (file_exists($sTempFileName) && filesize($sTempFileName) > 0) {
                        $aSize = getimagesize($sTempFileName); // try to obtain image info
                        if (!$aSize) {
                            @unlink($sTempFileName);
                            return;
                        }

                        // check for image type
                        switch($aSize[2]) {
                            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                                $sExt = '.jpg';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($sTempFileName);
                                break;
                            /*case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                                $sExt = '.gif';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefromgif($sTempFileName);
                                break;*/
                            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                                $sExt = '.png';

                                // create a new image from file 
                                $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($sTempFileName);
                                break;
                            default:
                                @unlink($sTempFileName);
                                return;
                        }

                        // create a new true color image
                        $vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );

                        // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
                        imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x1'], (int)$_POST['y1'], $iWidth, $iHeight, (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);

                        // define a result image filename
                        $sResultFileName = $sTempFileName . $sExt;

                        // output image to file
                        imagejpeg($vDstImg, $sResultFileName, $iJpgQuality);
                        @unlink($sTempFileName);

                        return $sResultFileName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$sImage = uploadImageFile();
echo '<img src="'.$sImage.'" />';
```

The other problem with it is I have no fall back option for the older browsers mainly IE8 and 9 because of it only being html5 based.

can anyone please help with any idea's please.